# Register value is not updated inside always @ loop

Tags: verilog, intel-fpga

I am relatively new to verilog, please help with this issue I am having.

Attached is a snippet of the code I am working on. The issue I am facing is, the regs - del1 and del2 are not correctly passing their values when used inside the "always @ " instruction set.

```
module pwm(clk,en,duty_cycle, switch, out, out1, out2, out3, pulT, pul1T, pul2T, pul3T, pulB, pul1B, pul2B, pul3B, ENABLE, sel, selo);  
input clk;  
input en;   
input ENABLE;
input switch;   
input [7:0]duty_cycle;  
output reg out; 
output reg out1;    
output reg out2;    
output reg out3;    
output reg pulT;   // 
output reg pul1T;  // 
output reg pul2T;  // 
output reg pul3T;  // 
output reg pulB;   // 
output reg pul1B;  // 
output reg pul2B;  // 
output reg pul3B;  //   
output reg sel; 
output wire selo; 

reg seloop;  //Q3   
reg seloon;  //Q4   
reg selop;   //Q1   
reg selon;   //Q2   

reg [7:0]counter;   
reg [7:0]next_counter;  
reg [8:0]ctr12; 
reg [8:0]next_ctr12;    
reg [8:0]ctr34; 
reg [8:0]next_ctr34;    
reg shift;  

reg del1;
reg del2;
parameter dt = 30;
parameter d11 = 60;
parameter d21 = 80;
parameter d12 = 110;
parameter d22 = 130;
parameter mp = 65;

clk_div2 u1 (.clk(clk), .clk_div2(clk_div2));   
assign selo = clk;  

always @ *
begin
case(switch)
1:  begin del1 <= d11; del2 <= d21; end
0: begin del1 <= d21; del2 <= d22; end
endcase
end 

always @ (posedge clk_div2) 
begin       
ctr12 = next_ctr12; 
ctr34 = next_ctr34; 
// --- Set -1 outputs --- //    
if (counter >= 255) begin   
sel <= ~sel;    
end 
// ---- S 1 & 2 -------//   
if (ctr12 <=(del1-dt)) begin //if (ctr34 <=(shift-dt)) begin    
selop = 0;  
selon = 1;  
end 
else if (ctr12 >(del1-dt) && ctr12 <= (del1+dt)) begin //else if (ctr34 >(shift-dt) && ctr34 <= (shift+dt)) begin   
selop = 0;  
selon = 0;  
end 
else if (ctr12 >(del1+dt) && ctr12 <= (del1+256-dt)) begin //else if (ctr34 >(shift+dt) && ctr34 <= (shift+256-dt)) begin   
selop = 1;  
selon = 0;  
end 
else if (ctr12 >(del1+256-dt) && ctr12 <= (del1+256+dt)) begin  //else if (ctr34 >(shift+256-dt) && ctr34 <= (shift+256+dt)) begin  
selop = 0;  
selon = 0;  
end 
else if (ctr12 >(del1+256+dt) && ctr12 <= (512)) begin //else if (ctr34 >(shift+256+dt) && ctr34 <= 512) begin  
selop = 0;  
selon = 1;  
end 
else begin  
selop = 0;  
selon = 0;  
end 
//----------- S 3 & 4 ------//  
if (ctr34 <=(del2-dt)) begin //if (ctr34 <=(shift-dt)) begin    
seloop = 1; 
seloon = 0; 
end 
else if (ctr34 >(del2-dt) && ctr34 <= (del2+dt)) begin //else if (ctr34 >(shift-dt) && ctr34 <= (shift+dt)) begin   
seloop = 0; 
seloon = 0; 
end 
else if (ctr34 >(del2+dt) && ctr34 <= (del2+256-dt)) begin //else if (ctr34 >(shift+dt) && ctr34 <= (shift+256-dt)) begin   
seloop = 0; 
seloon = 1; 
end 
else if (ctr34 >(del2+256-dt) && ctr34 <= (del2+256+dt)) begin  //else if (ctr34 >(shift+256-dt) && ctr34 <= (shift+256+dt)) begin  
seloop = 0; 
seloon = 0; 
end 
else if (ctr34 >(del2+256+dt) && ctr34 <= (512)) begin //else if (ctr34 >(shift+256+dt) && ctr34 <= 512) begin  
seloop = 1; 
seloon = 0; 
end 
else begin  
seloop = 0; 
seloon = 0; 
end 
//selo = clk;   
end 
...
...
...
...
next_ctr12 = ctr12+1;   
next_ctr34 = ctr34+1;   
endmodule
/////////////////////////
module clk_div2(clk,clk_div2);  
input clk;  
output clk_div2;    
reg clk_div2 = 1;   

reg [2:0]counter;   
reg [2:0]next_counter;  

always @ (posedge clk)  
begin   
counter = counter +1;   
if (counter>=2) begin   
clk_div2 <= ~clk_div2;  
counter = 0;    
end 
end 
endmodule
```

My expectation was that if the "switch" toggles, del1 and del2 will get different values and the instruction set under "always @" will change accordingly. But its not working at all.
I did some research on this and my guess is the regs dela1 and del2 are not resetting and hence it is in dont care condition. But I guess I dont know how to reset it, can you please help? What else might be the reason?
I also tried setting del1 and del2 as wire, that approach doesnot work as well. Is something wrong with the way "always@" is set up?

Comment: Start with fixing your assignments, they are just the wrong way around: In the always @( * ) you should use blocking assignments `=`. In the  @ (posedge clk_div2) you should use non blocking: `<=`.  Then get a waveform display running and check what is happening. Oh and you should avoid using "derived clocks" (clk_div2). Use one general clock with an enable.

Comment: Your code is kind of a mess. You are using non-blocking assignments for combinational logic, and mixing blocking and non-blocking assignments in a clocked block. Have you defined a `clk_div2` module for U1? Why are you using the same identifier (clk_div2) for different purposes?

Comment: Please post a minimum verifiable example they demonstrates the issue. Please also properly indent and format the code

Comment: Sorry forgot the u1, added. I will fix the blocking and nonblocking issues tonight and try it out. Elliot, I see what you mean, that might be an error on my part, I will try to fix that too. But does that explain del1 and del2 being dont care?

Comment: `del1` and `del1` are defined as `reg` which is only 1-bit. Try defining them as `reg [7:0]`.

Comment: wow, I couldn't have made a sillier mistake, thanks Greg. Thanks all for pointing to the issue of blocking/non blocking, still learning. I could accept Gregs comment if you post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`del1` and `del1` are defined as `reg` which is only 1-bit. Try defining them as `reg [7:0]`.

Also fold in Oldfart's and Elliot's suggestion of fixing blocking (`=`) / non-blocking (`<=`) assignments. Combinational logic (eg: `always @*`) should use blocking (`=`). Sequentail logic (eg: `always @(posesge clk)`) should use non-blocking (`<=`)